# How to find the class a string describes in Java

Tags: java, types, getmethod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Class.getArrayType in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719932/class-getarraytype-in-java)

I need to get the class for a type that is represented by a string.  I am trying to invoke getMethod and I only have a list of strings for the types it requires.

Class.forName(str) works when str is a simple class, but not, for example, with an array like so:

```
Class<?>[] typeClasses = new Class<?>[]{Class.forName("my.type.class[]")};
Method method = someClass.getMethod(methodString, typeClasses);
```

Comment: What is `getMethod(...)` a member of? Is there a static import or a static method definition missing from the code snippet?

Comment: what is the signature of Method you are trying to invoke?

Comment: Sorry about that-- I have edited getMethod to include a class object.

Comment: @Priyank-- An example is *public static void myMethod(String[] myString)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get hold of the `Class` object for an array type is to call `getClass()` on an array instance that you created reflectively; e.g.

```
Class someClass = Some.class;
Class someArrayClass = java.reflect.Array.newInstance(someClass, 0).getClass();
```

You can also use `Class.forName()` but you need to specify the class name in internal form; e.g. the class name for an `Object[]` is `"[Ljava.lang.Object;"`.  See [Class.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) for details of the class name format.

Comment: Thanks-- but I only have a string describing the type, for example "String[]".

Comment: Well you will need to parse it to extract the base type name, convert it to a fully qualified name, and then use one of the methods in my Answer.  I'd code it for you ... but someone has bent my spoon.

Comment: You second method works for me.  I can use the [L notation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the string you're passing in the example is not the correct string representation of that class. This example code runs fine and prints true:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "hello" };
Class<?> arrayClass = array.getClass();
String stringClass = arrayClass.getName();
Class<?> parsedClass;
try {
    parsedClass = Class.forName(stringClass);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
System.out.println(arrayClass.equals(parsedClass));
```

See the Javadoc for [Class#getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) for examples on how to represent array types as strings. If these strings are coming from somewhere else and you know what format to expect you could write a method to convert the strings into the format expected by the classloader.